# How to determine if custom extension has frontend page/controller

Tags: module, magento-1, extensions, frontend

I'm working with a custom extension that was developed for our site by our previous developer some time ago. The extension was fully built out and met the company's needs at the time however there is very little documentation on the extension's full capabilities and we can no longer reach the developer.

With that being said: We have an extension that essentially manages magazine/publication subscriptions. When Magento users are logged in, they should be able to manage their subscriptions at a dedicated URL that is populated by this extension. We can’t seem to find that URL but there are code comments in the extension that imply that this page exists and is generated by the module. I’m trying to determine the namespace of the URL but don’t know where or what to check for.

I started by looking into the extension’s *controllers* directory and I see several files that appear promising but I couldn’t determine the URL that I was supposed to be visiting.

**My Question:** Where would I look in an extension’s files to determine if there is a URL accessible page or controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check in the module's  `config.xml`.

So go to app/code/community(or local)/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml

And check where it defines the frontend router:

```
<config>
    ...
    <frontend>
        <routers>
          ....
        </routers>   
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks Mayers Dev! That was exactly the case with this. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to Mayers answer you could use something like this in the .phtml file in order to get what sort of controller is used.

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getControllerName()
```